# Who is the con man that Bailey wants help deporting?

Tags: mass-effect-3

On one of my frequent trips to the great shopping mall in space, aka the Citadel, I decided to stop by the Spectre office and check the terminal.  There's an item in the system where Bailey wishes to have Spectre authorization to deport a con man off the station.  While I love that I apparently have the power to determine who stays and who goes, I have to wonder: who is this con man, and will it hurt me in the long run if I have him deported?  Why should a Spectre even care about this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't ever actually *see* the con man in question, but you can hear a pair of C-Sec officers outside Purgatory discussing it. Once you hear enough of their story, the item appears in the spectre offices.

Deporting him will give you some war assets by improving the Citadel Defense Force - [7, according to Wikia.](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/War_Assets/Alien#Citadel_Defense_Force)